# Add Multiple values via the same IN in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Let's assume the following MySQL stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetJobs`(IN `jobStatus` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET utf8)
BEGIN
 SELECT * 
 FROM `jobs` 
 WHERE status IN ( jobStatus );
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When the value of JobStatus is a single integer, eg `0` or `4`, it works.
But when it is eg `0,1` it fails.

Any idea on how to achieve the above to work for any number of IDs?
eg 0,1
eg 1,2,3,5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is not an issue, use `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(status, in_jobStatus) > 0
```

Note:  You should prefix parameters in a stored procedure/function so they are less likely to have the same name as a column in a table.